# C++ и сокеты

Tags: сокет, c++

Доброго времени суток. Возникла необходимость создать сокет. Искал в интернете пример нормальный с комментариями, но нормальный найти не смог (может, руки кривые)...

Буду благодарен за пример с комментариями. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ничего против boost'а не имеете, то множество примеров на boost::asio - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

Answer (score 4):

Cоздать сокет - это просто вызвать `socket` с правильными параметрами. Они то разные бывают. В свое время мне сильно помогла вот [эта](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) мегастатья (там есть на разных языках, в html/pdf)

Для тех, кому с английским сложновато, можно почитать вольные и незавершенные переводы на [русский](http://slav0nic.org.ua/static/books/C_Cpp/%5BRU%5DBeej's%20Guide%20to%20Network%20Programming.htm) и украинский.

Comment: а на русском есть что-нибудь?

Comment: [есть](http://slav0nic.org.ua/static/books/C_Cpp/%5BRU%5DBeej's%20Guide%20to%20Network%20Programming.htm). Но кто гарантирует его качество?:) рекомендую сверяться с англоязычным оригиналом. Ну и подучивать английский.

Comment: Спасибо. Насчет английского знаю - моя вечная проблема :)

Answer (score 0):

Мне в свое время помогла статья с развернутым примером сервера и соответствующего ему клиента: [Running the Winsock Client and Server Code Sample (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737889(v=vs.85).aspx)

p.s.: в текущем состоянии `MSDN`, искать старые статьи все сложнее и сложнее

Answer (score 0):

Я в свое время учился вот по этой статье: http://www.rsdn.ru/article/unix/sockets.xml

А вообще поиск по "программирование сокетов" может помочь гораздо больше